# Static files not rendering ASP .NET MVC (.NET Framework 4.8)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue where the browser does not render static files received from the server when I run the application with 200 status codes for all files. The page appears blank on load. The page title and favicon are visible though.

[Network requests screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gqQO.png)

Here is my **BundleConfig.cs** file:

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace XYZ.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
            // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **global.asax.cs** file :

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;
using XYZ.Library.Services;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace XYZ.Web
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            RegisterAutofac();
        }
        private void RegisterAutofac()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            //Register MVC controllers
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly);

            //Register IUserService
            builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerRequest();

            //Set the dependency resolver to Autofac
            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **Views/Home/Index.cshtml** file that provides the HTML markup:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" async>
    <link async rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-instantsearch-theme-algolia@4.0.0/style.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin="" async />
    <title>XYZ/title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.c764a889.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.XYZ= {};
        window.XYZ.apiBaseUrl = '/api';
        window.XYZ.loginUrl = '/';
        window.XYZ.version = '2.2';
        window.XYZ.tokenUrl = '/Login';
    </script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.1cf49c64.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of my solution's structure:

[project solution structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBaDV.png)

Here is a screenshot showing the static files

[static files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3ATL.png)

My **RouteConfig.cs** code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace XYZ.Web
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
        }
    }
}
```

What could be wrong in my code?

I've tried changing the static files and checking if all project files are present in the solution. I also tried to run the application with `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` set to `false` but it didn't work.

Comment: @mason I've updated the question for more context. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I've added that and RouteConfig.cs and static folder contents @mason

Comment: I see no reference to some of the bundles in your HTML, such as jquery. So if you don't reference it, why should the page pull it down?

Comment: That code seems redundant as I don't need the jquery files for the application to run. I'll remove that. I found the issue. All of the required files in `static` weren't being referenced. I added the references into the Index.cshtml file and that did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and it was a small error on my side. I fixed the issue by correctly referencing all required static files in the Views/Home/Index.cshtml file. The updated Index.cshtml file is

```
@{ Layout = null; }<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>Parsing Portal</title>
    <link href="/static/css/2.83a79fa7.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/static/css/main.c764a889.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/static/js/2.35ccfd07.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.1cf49c64.chunk.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Install Static Content on the IIS (Internet Information Services)
[image]